# In any form of ball game, is there a term for when a ball gets caught in the wind and changes the play or affects how the play ends?

Tags: terminology

So far I haven't had any luck trying to find an answer to this question, but I am not all that familiar with sports as a whole - only baseball, and Fly Rule doesn't seem to apply. A term from -any- outdoor ball sport would be acceptable,

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no rules regarding the situation you described. In many sports, wind plays a large factor in how the ball travels through the air (American Football, Soccer (Football), Baseball, Golf, etc).

In Track and Field, there are rules that stipulate that the wind speed has to be under a certain amount for a record to be counted (see wind assistance).